# Manipulation JSON with Lodash

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

using this code `let result = _.groupBy(obj, 'type');` I have this return:

```
{
    "success": [{
        "type": "success",
        "messages": "Assignment saved."
    }, {
        "type": "success",
        "messages": "Assignment saved."
    }, {
        "type": "success",
        "messages": "Assignment saved."
    }]
}
```

But I need to convert to this:

```
{
    "error": ["Error msg", "Error 2 msg", "Error 3 msg"],
    "notice": ["Notice 1 msg", "Notice 2 msg"],
    "success": ["Success 1 msg", "Success 2 msg", "Success 3 msg"]
}
```

What should I do differently in my code?

Some configuration on Lodash that I'm missing?

Comment: well they are getting grouped by type, it's not meant to modify the objects

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy

Comment: yeap, I need to to find a way to do it. I need to `groupBy` and extra adjust my `return` to get an `array`. But I could not find any `documentation` on how to manipulate the `object`, using `groupBy`.

Comment: So, in the input object you already have a key called `success` which is a array? Or its just a result of `groupBy`? similarly do you have separate array for `error` , `notice`? or all the data you have in one array and the name of .the key of the array is `success` (which is pretty awkward). can you show us the raw input?

Comment: You should paste the original `obj`. Also, the expected value shows keys and messages not shown in the other object, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/25410/) for a working solution.
With this solution you are not locked to the same 3 type of message.

Ive used `_.groupBy`

```
let list = [{type: "success", message: "msg1"},{type: "success", message: "msg2"},{type: "success", message: "msg3"},{type: "notice", message: "msg1"}, {type: "notice", message: "msg2"}, {type: "error", message: "msg1"}]

console.log("\n\n---------Full initial list of events");
console.log(list);

console.log("\n\n---------Events grouped by type");
console.log(_.groupBy(list, 'type'));

console.log("\n\n---------Your format");
let groups = _.groupBy(list, 'type')
let keys = Object.keys(groups);
for (let key of keys) {
    groups[key] = groups[key].map(elem => elem.message)
}
console.log(groups);
```

Comment: you cold also do `_.forOwn(groups, v => v.map((v2,i,a) => a[i] = v2.message))`

Answer (score 1):

The code included in the question is confusing. Something like this?

```
const result = _(obj)
  .groupBy("type")
  .mapValues(objs => objs.map(o => o.messages))
  .value()
```

Comment: @CoderPi: 1) Is lodash loaded in this fiddle?, 2) OP has `messages` as key, not `message`.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries are not always the way to go:

```js
function groupMessagesByType(dataIn) {
  let dataOut = {}
  
  for(var i = 0; i < dataIn.length; ++i) {
    var type = dataIn[i].type
    if(typeof dataOut[type] == "undefined") {
      dataOut[type] = []
    }
    dataOut[type].push(dataIn[i].messages)
  }

  return dataOut
}

// Example:
var data = [{
        "type": "success",
        "messages": "Assignment saved."
    }, {
        "type": "success",
        "messages": "Assignment saved."
    }, {
        "type": "error",
        "messages": "Error msg."
    }]
console.log(groupMessagesByType(data))
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works.
I also had made something similar, but I was trying to use LoDash in this case but is not possible or I'm missing some information. Thanks again, man.

Comment: You can do anything without libraries, but if using them makes the code more declarative (and probably shorter) using well-known functional abstractions (map, filter, sortBy, and so on), why not?